# Question on the limit of a sequence: $\lim_{n}b_{n}=a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{n}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=1,$ then $\lim_{n}a_{n}=a.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Question 10 [here](http://archeia.moec.gov.cy/ed/233/2019_11_19_517_lyseis.pdf) asks (it's in Greek so I'll translate it):
Let $(a_{n})_{n},~(b_{n})_{n}$ two sequences such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n}b_{n}=a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=1.$
Show that
$$\lim_{n}a_{n}=a.$$

The solution given there goes along the lines that one can find a $n_{0}$ such that $b_{n}\neq0,~\forall n\geq n_{0}$ and then just plug in the limits.

I've tried to give a rigorous proof using the definition of the limit and I want to know if I am on the right track or I'm just writing nonsense. Here's my solution:
Let $\epsilon>0$.
Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n}b_{n}=a$, there exists $n_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|b_{n}-a|<1,~\forall n\geq n_{1},$ i.e.
$$|b_{n}|<1+|a|,~\forall n\geq n_{1}.$$
Now, since $\displaystyle\lim_{n}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=1,$ there exists $n_{2}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\left|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}-1\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|a|)},~\forall n\geq n_{2}.$$
Set $N=\max\{n_{1},n_{2}\}.$ Then
\begin{eqnarray*}|a_{n}-a|&=&\left|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}b_{n}-b_{n}+b_{n}-a\right|\\
 &\leq&|b_{n}|\cdot\left|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}-1\right|+|b_{n}-a|\\
 &<&(1+|a|)\frac{\epsilon}{2(1+|a|)}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon,
 \end{eqnarray*}
$\forall~n\geq N.$
Hence
$$\lim_{n}a_{n}=a.$$

Comment: @SamaelManasseh The statement is actually true for any $\epsilon>0$ and thus also for $\epsilon=1$. The important idea here is that the series is bounded for large enough $n$. The proof looks good to me.

Comment: yes! this is correct,

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems correct, as a slightly different and maybe more simple way we have

- $|b_{n}-a|<\epsilon_1,~\forall n\geq n_{1}$
- $\left|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}-1\right|<\epsilon_2,~\forall n\geq n_{2}$

and therefore by $N=\max\{n_{1},n_{2}\}$ we have that $\forall\epsilon >0$

\begin{eqnarray*}|a_{n}-a|&=&\left|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}b_{n}-b_{n}+b_{n}-a\right|\\
 &\leq&|b_{n}|\cdot\left|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}-1\right|+|b_{n}-a|\\
 &<&|b_{n}|\epsilon_2+\epsilon_1<2|a|\epsilon_2+\epsilon_1<\epsilon
 \end{eqnarray*}
$\forall~n\geq N$ since $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are arbitrarily small.